# Force acting on spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, spring

From newton's 2nd law,we know net force=$ma$. Now since in ideal cases,springs are massless,force on spring should be $ma=0\times a=0$. But still forces like restoring force,weight of a body hanging to it etc work on spring.How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The force exerted by a spring is $F=-kx$. Newton’s 2nd law would be used to determine the acceleration of a mass attached to the spring, id est $ma=-kx$. The first part is describing the mass on the spring; the right hand side is the force the spring exerts. The spring is what exerts the force; no force is exerted on the spring in the ideal case.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that it is the net force which is proportional to the acceleration. So it is not correct that the force on a massless spring must be zero, only that the net force must be zero. Thus, you can certainly apply a force to one side of a massless spring provided you apply an equal and opposite force to the other side.

Comment: But see that the spring with a block attached to it can oscillate about its mean position,and as we all know simple harmonic motion has acceleration $a=-\omega^2 y$,here the net force doesn't appear to $0$ since acceleration exists.

Comment: @green_blue How much net force is required to accelerate a massless object by $-\omega^2 y$ according to Newton’s 2nd law?

Comment: I mean it was deduced via $-kx=F=ma$ so $a=-\frac{k}{m}x$,putting $\frac{k}{m}=\omega^2$,we get our desired result. Obviously there has to be a net force or else how could we get that acceleration?

Comment: @green_blue please answer the question I asked previously.

Comment: $ma=m\omega^2y$ i believe

Comment: @green_blue and since $m=0$ the force is …?

Answer (score 1):

A simple spring is an example of a structure which, ideally, exerts an linear restoring force based on the distortion of the structure. The magnitude of the force is $kX$, where $X$ is the amount of *instantaneous* distortion and $k$ is the proportionality constant, *aka* spring constant.

In order for the spring to exert a force it must be distorted. In order to distort the spring two *different* forces must be applied to the "ends" (or different parts) of the spring. The difference in these forces produces an acceleration to the material of the spring so that it stretches or compresses until a new equilibrium *throughout* the spring is established and the spring stops distorting.

In most introductory spring problems one end of the spring is fixed, usually to a wall or ceiling, and we ignore the force exerted at that fixed end. Also, we are usually focusing (in introductory problems) on the force the spring exerts at the other end rather than the force acting on the spring. But, conceptually, the spring *itself* always exerts magnitude $kX$ at both ends, all the time. The spring distorts, as mentioned before, because the force the wall at the fixed end exerts on the spring is *different* from force exerted on the spring at the other end until an equilibrium position is reached. In introductory spring problems, one usually doesn't deal with the kinematics of the spring, but only equilibrium positions.  In post-introductory mechanics, dynamic kinematics will show the oscillatory nature of linear resotring forces when the force applied to a spring is greater or less than $kX$, resulting in an acceleration.

Comment: Consider a string which is massless and a mass $m$ attached to it,we know tension is equal at every points in the string.But  $mg$ force is acting on the spring and tension is acting on the object.It seems that net force is not $0$ in case of strings.

Answer (score 1):

A massless spring is only considered in idealised cases where there are masses attached. You don't apply forces to things that are assumed to have no mass otherwise you get infinite acceleration (just as impossible as zero mass), or alternatively you would conclude as you did that the force had to be zero. If the spring is massless but has a stiffness assigned to it however, it will still exert a restoring force, it will still support the weight of a body hanging from it and work can still be done against it.

Answer (score 1):

*. . . . weight of a body hanging to it . . . .*

If one end  of a massless spring has no force acting on it then the spring cannot be compressed or extended.

Consider a massless spring connected at both end, eg the top end of the spring connected to a ceiling and the bottom end of the spring connected to the body which is in static equilibrium.
The two equal and opposite forces acting on the body are the gravitational attraction due to the Earth, $F_{\rm g}$, downwards and the force due to the spring, $F_{\rm s}$, upwards, ie a net force of zero acting on the body.
The two equal in magnitude $F_{\rm s}$ and opposite forces acting on the **spring** are the force due to the body downwards and the force due to the ceiling upwards, ie a net force of zero on the spring.

In lots of examples one end of a spring is connected to a very massive body like the Earth which means that the approximation can be made that that end of the spring does not move.
This is really massless no different to making the approximation that when a body is in free fall downwards the Earth does not move upwards.

Comment: Okay but what about the case when the spring does oscillations?Since it is doing SHM,it has an accelaration,which implies net force isn't $0$ in this case.

Comment: I think that you are missing the point that you are considering an idealised situation.  That being the point another way of approaching this is to say that the mass of the spring is much, much less than the mass of the body. The spring then does have a net force on it but it can be neglected compared with the the force acting on the body.

Answer (score 1):

Promoted from comments:

> Usually, when people discuss ideal springs, it is just to get rid of any complexities regarding the spring itself and only keep the force exerted by the spring on an object. The spring itself can apply forces on any object and be subject to an elongation etc. Ideal springs also don't really exists... they are just used for modelling